# Can not find or load main class - classloader issue

Tags: java, classloader

I know this question has been asked before, but I’ve read through most of them and still can’t figure out my problem.

I’ve compiled the below code into *"HelloWorld.class"* located in the directory shown below.

```
package helloworld;

    public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

[image]

But I cannot get the .class file to run using the Java command on Window Command Prompt:

[image]

I believe my PATH and CLASSPATH are set correctly (as shown below).  But I still can’t find the class.  Any ideas why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: And for the record: all of that information in your question represents **text**. You don't create screenshots of your console; you mark the **text** and you copy that **text** as **text** into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the class is not HelloWorld. It goes like:

```
 java helloworld.HelloWorld
```

and you have to call that from the directory **above** helloworld.

In other words: the package name is **part** of the class name. When you invoke java; you have to provide that *full* name; and the **classpath** needs to point to the directory that **contains** that package.